# t-sql possible deadlock solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking, deadlock

I am running time taking (few hours) procedure, doing inserts, updates with selects. Is there any possibility to make lowest possible locking on used data? I think I got a deadlock problem here when my other procedures tries to do selects on that data.

I would love to make my insert/delete/update statements in my procedure that are using select on big table date not to block that data in any way (or maybe at least not for selects).

Would using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` solve the problem? I read also about snapshots, but database is too big to set it ON.

Comment: `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` will **always** exclusively lock the rows they affect. And if you do more than 5000 operations in a single transaction, the lock might be **escalated** to the table level, thus preventing any `SELECT` from those tables. Try to update your `UPDATE` etc. statements in small batches and if ever possible at times when your database isn't used much ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` at the top of each query batch will help solve the issue of deadlocks. Keep in mind these will be dirty reads, as in you will not be reading any "committed" transactions when using this setting. I use this statement a lot to avoid causing deadlock issues in production environments with high traffic database tables.

Read a full list of pros & cons of using `read uncommitted` here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tamarick_hill/archive/2013/05/06/pros-cons-of-using-read-uncommitted-and-nolock.aspx